# The identity certificate for mdm profile could not be found

Tags: ios, mdm

I was trying to develop a MDM solution for iOS and I would like to test MDM with both methods of distributing device identity via PKCS12 and SCEP. Currently I am doing it using PKCS12, so here is what I am doing:

1. Send a Profile Service profile to the device asking its device id, IMEI, Version etc.
2. Device responds with the requested attribute - signed using the Apple Provided Certificate.
3. I now issue a PKCS12 certificate to the device using the credentials payload.
4. Device responds again with its attributes - this time signed using the above certificate.
5. I deliver an MDM payload setting the IdentityCertificateUUID to the payload UUID of the certificate issued in step 3.

I get profile could not be installed. Upon examining the logs, I found out the error The identity certificate for mdm profile com.mdm.xyz could not be found.

If at Step 5, I issue the MDM profile with a new certificaate included in the payload everything works. I am not sure if this is the right way to issue another certificate. I was thinking to utilize the same certificate issued at Step 3.

I think I am doing something wrong here and this may not be the correct way. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I get this error too, when *encrypting* the profile generated in step 5 with the certificate provided in step 2. I'm not generating a certificate for the device as part of enrolment. I found that delivering a profile encrypted to a certificate previously installed on the device successful, however. How are you generating the private key for the cert you (optionally) generate in step 5?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in step 5 the same certificate that you use in step 3. In such case MDM profile is installed successfully.